# Reading files from a CD-ROM

Tags: windows, optical

I have a functional CD-ROM with lots of Windows stuff inside. I know that the executables won't run on Ubuntu, but I cannot even get the system to mount it.

I'm sure it's user error. But, I'd love to access the files/folders on this disk as there are some PDF files that are very important for me.

Can anybody help me?

*edit: Adding in pertinent info*

I'm on a Dell Inspiron 5559
Intel® Core™ i7-6500U CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4
Ubuntu 18.04

When I put a disk like this in the tray spins up, then nothing. File manager doesn't see it. Disk Manager app won't mount it. It's like it's not there.

Music disks, DVDs, & blank discs all register fine and appropriate apps open.

Here's the return from **lshw** with a Windows disk in:

```
        *-cdrom
         description: DVD-RAM writer
         product: DVD+-RW DU-8A5LH
         vendor: PLDS
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/cdrom
         logical name: /dev/cdrw
         logical name: /dev/dvd
         logical name: /dev/dvdrw
         logical name: /dev/sr0
         version: DD11
         capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
         configuration: ansiversion=5 status=ready
       *-medium
            physical id: 0
            logical name: /dev/cdrom
```

Attempting to manually mount it via

```
mount /dev/sr0 /mnt
```

Returns

```
mount: /mnt: no medium found on /dev/sr0.
```

But the disk is in there. And from lshw above, the system knows it's there.

When running **journalctl --follow**, I do not understand any of the output that occurs when I insert the CD. In fact, it looks irrelevant (if so, I'll delete later). That all looks like network traffic.

```
Aug 30 06:58:33 mattbuntu kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=00:1e:64:f9:28:33:6c:ad:f8:36:6a:ec:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.2 DST=192.168.1.93 LEN=543 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=56657 DPT=43265 LEN=523 
Aug 30 06:58:34 mattbuntu kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=00:1e:64:f9:28:33:a4:77:33:85:8c:e8:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.3 DST=192.168.1.93 LEN=544 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=47667 DPT=43265 LEN=524 
Aug 30 06:58:34 mattbuntu kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=00:1e:64:f9:28:33:6c:ad:f8:36:6a:ec:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.2 DST=192.168.1.93 LEN=543 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=54085 DPT=43265 LEN=523 
Aug 30 06:58:35 mattbuntu kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=00:1e:64:f9:28:33:a4:77:33:85:8c:e8:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.3 DST=192.168.1.93 LEN=544 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=35654 DPT=43265 LEN=524 
Aug 30 06:58:35 mattbuntu kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=00:1e:64:f9:28:33:a4:77:33:85:8c:e8:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.3 DST=192.168.1.93 LEN=544 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=49123 DPT=43265 LEN=524 
Aug 30 06:58:35 mattbuntu kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=00:1e:64:f9:28:33:6c:ad:f8:36:6a:ec:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.2 DST=192.168.1.93 LEN=543 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=43700 DPT=43265 LEN=523
```

I did also finally get some returns on:

```
wodim -atip dev=/dev/sr0


Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 5
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'PLDS    '
Identification : 'DVD+-RW DU-8A5LH'
Revision       : 'DD11'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW.
wodim: Cannot load media with this drive!
wodim: Try to load media by hand.
Using generic SCSI-3/mmc   CD-R/CD-RW driver (mmc_cdr).
Driver flags   : MMC-3 SWABAUDIO BURNFREE FORCESPEED 
Supported modes: TAO PACKET SAO SAO/R96P SAO/R96R RAW/R16 RAW/R96P RAW/R96R
wodim: Cannot load media with this drive!
wodim: Try to load media by hand.
wodim: Cannot load media.
```

Also, here is the result from cd-info:

```
matthewlhudson@mattbuntu:~$ cd-info
cd-info version 1.0.0 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (c) 2003-2005, 2007-2008, 2011-2015, 2017 R. Bernstein
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
CD location   : /dev/cdrom
CD driver name: GNU/Linux
   access mode: IOCTL

Vendor                      : PLDS    
Model                       : DVD+-RW DU-8A5LH
Revision                    : DD11
Hardware                                  : CD-ROM or DVD
Can eject                                 : Yes
Can close tray                            : Yes
Can disable manual eject                  : Yes
Can select juke-box disc                  : No

Can set drive speed                       : No
Can read multiple sessions (e.g. PhotoCD) : Yes
Can hard reset device                     : Yes

Reading....
  Can read Mode 2 Form 1                  : Yes
  Can read Mode 2 Form 2                  : Yes
  Can read (S)VCD (i.e. Mode 2 Form 1/2)  : Yes
  Can read C2 Errors                      : Yes
  Can read IRSC                           : Yes
  Can read Media Channel Number (or UPC)  : Yes
  Can play audio                          : Yes
  Can read CD-DA                          : Yes
  Can read CD-R                           : Yes
  Can read CD-RW                          : Yes
  Can read DVD-ROM                        : Yes

Writing....
  Can write CD-RW                         : Yes
  Can write DVD-R                         : Yes
  Can write DVD-RAM                       : Yes
  Can write DVD-RW                        : No
  Can write DVD+RW                        : No
__________________________________

Disc mode is listed as: Error in getting information
++ WARN: error in ioctl CDROMREADTOCHDR: No medium found

cd-info: Can't get first track number. I give up.
```

I wonder how will I know if it's the drive or the disk. The disk works on other machines. The drive works with Music disks & blank disks. So, both work in some cases.

Comment: Would be crear if you could provide some diagnostic information. Do you know how to run commands in a terminal?

Comment: Yes, I am able to run terminal commands. I'd be happy to give you whatever diagnostic info would help!

Comment: Are you getting any errors? and what did you try. What version of Ubuntu? I grabbed a cdrom at random (quickverse, windows software) inserted it, and a short time later the disc span up & a notification with the disc name appeared at the top of the screen with close or 'open with files' options. I am using GNOME or the standard Ubuntu 18.10 UI (same as 18.04).  If I open term and enter `lsblk` at the bottom of my devices I see "sr0     11:0    1 109.1M  0 rom  /media/guiverc/5532D_QV_CD" which is the CD.  More details of your version, and what you tried, if the drive span up are helpful...

Comment: Eject the CDROM. Start `journalctl --follow` in a terminal window. Insert the CDROM. Any interesting log info from `journalctl --follow`?

Comment: I'll add edits above.

Comment: try `mount /dev/cdrom /mnt`

Comment: Can you post the output of the following commands (prefixing them with `sudo`)?  1.  `cd-info`   2.  `wodim -atip dev=/dev/sr0`  3.  `dvd+rw-mediainfo`   4.  `udisks --dump`  5.  `/lib/udev/cdrom_id -d /dev/sr0`

Comment: You can try to run the following command to get a disk image: `sudo ddrescue /dev/sr0 /home/$USER/DVD.{iso,log}`

Comment: I'm obviously not doing this correctly. Every single one of these commands results in "command not found". I'm doing "sudo" then the command you suggested in the `code`.

Comment: Many tools may not be installed by default. That's why you're getting the `command not found` error. If you run the commands without `sudo`, the system will suggest you the packages to install.

Comment: I would recommend you to try reading the disk in another computer with Windows, though I suspect that your problem is related to a faulty CD or a faulty disk drive. In the worst case, you can try to contact a data recovery enterprise.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Thank you for your response! No worries on timing. Life is generally busy for everyone!! I also added the returns from cd-info. I wonder how will I know if it's the drive or the disk. The disk works on other machines. The drive works with Music disks & blank disks. So, both work in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

You say that system can't mount it!

Did u try manual mount from the terminal?
as root you would be able to mount cdrom with no issues:

```
mount /dev/sr0 /mnt
```

or create your own directory and instead in /mnt you mount it on that directory.

Comment: Attempting to mount returns:
`mount: /mnt: no medium found on /dev/sr0.`
But it's in there. And the system knows it (see edits to question above).